# Linear combination of orthogonal projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello!

Let $v_i\in R^d$ $(i=1,...,n,n>d)$ be unit-length vectors ($v_i^Tv_i=1$). Then $v_iv_i^T$ is an *orthogonal projection matrix*, which has many elegant properties. Now consider a linear combination of these orthogonal matrices
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i v_i^T$$
where $c_i$ are positive scalars and $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i=1$. **My question is**: what $v_i$ can make the linear combination of these orthogonal matrices be an identity matrix? That is: how to find $v_i$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i v_i^T=\frac{1}{d}I$$

Thanks.

Comment: I forget to note $c_i\le 1/d$ since it is a necessary condition for $\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv_iv_i^T=I$

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition for your question as stated is that $d=1$ ;). The trace of $\sum c_i v_i v_i^{T}$ is indeed $\sum c_i=1$. You probably rather want that $\sum c_i=d$.

Comment: Thanks Mikael: You are right. I should let $\sum c_i=d$ or equivalently I can let $\sum c_i v_i v_i^T=\frac{1}{d}I$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make the change Mikael suggests, you are basically looking at tight frames. $c_i^{1/2} v_i$ should be the image under an orthogonal projection of an orthonormal basis from some $n$ dimensional superspace.

Comment: With the stated assumption that the $v_i$ are unit vectors, I think the exact terminology here is "normalized tight frames".

Comment: @Bill: it seems what I am looking for. Thank you.